# Continue for loop after caught Exception

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator

I am reading a large (2Gb) file via `csv.DictReader` (for what it matters). Somewhere deep in the file there is an issue with the coding and I get a `UnicodeDecodeError`. Looking at the error message I see that the error is raised in the implicit `__next__` in my `for` loop.

Code stub would look at follows:

```py
import csv

with open("myfile.csv", newline="") as f:
    c = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in c: # here the error is happening
       pass
```

I want to use a `try-except` pattern to catch any reading error, logging a meaningful message and continue reading through the file.

How could I achieve that? I cannot use `continue` outside the loop (i.e. in the `except` block) so I guess I would need to rewrite the `for` loop in order not to use the implicit form but an explicit one, but as I am fairly new to python, I do not know how to do that in the most pythonic way.

---

To simulate the error look at the following toy example:

```py
class MyIterator:
    def __init__(self, mclass):
        self._mclass = mclass
        self._index = 0

    def __next__(self):
        if self._index == 3:
            # simulate an error in a file read
            self._index += 1
            raise Exception("simulated error"
        elif self._index < 5:
            self._index += 1
            return self._index - 1
        # End of Iteration
        raise StopIteration


class MyClass:
    def __iter__(self):
        return MyIterator(self)

obj = MyClass()
try:
    for result in obj:
        print(result)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception covered")
    ## does not work for obvious reasons:
    # continue
```

Comment: Put the `try...except` inside the loop?

Comment: Wait scratch that - didn't read properly. If you could continue the loop, how would it know where to start reading again? Starting where in the file the exception occurred would only raise another exception.

Comment: Hm, I thought that the error is raised in this line `for line in c:`, would the `try` catch that if it is inside the loop`?

Comment: Yeah - where the exception actually is thrown is vital to knowing how to go about solving it.

Comment: Ok, so what is the normal pattern then in this cases to simply skip lines where there is an IO error happening?

Comment: If you can - but there is no way of knowing that the rest of the file is any better. I'd just ask the user to verify the integrity. "this was the last item that could read, then an error occured. Please investigate why and try again when resolved" - or you're going to have real issues informing the user about which entries did not import...

Comment: Well, all I want is to skip lines which are not decodable. If there are many, fine, but I do not want my program to stop on the first line, but to simply skip that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your object in an iter and call next on it in a while loop

```
done = False
obj = iter(MyClass())
while not done:
    try:
        data = next(obj)
    except StopIteration:
        done = True
    except Exception:
         print("process error here and continue")
```

Comment: in the solution yield would reduce the size of code ... and make it easier...
and also ... you just transform the for into a while

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, instead of trying to catch the error on `next`, one can pass the `errors` argument to `open`, which dictates exactly how to deal with codec errors.

Answer (score -1):

What python version are u using?
Also why not using yield ( see [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lmCu8wz8ro&feature=youtu.be&t=26) )

You can return instead of raise. If you know if type(variable) is Exception you cand process information.

Comment: Seeing the accepted result:
    for result in obj:
        `if type(result) is Exception:
            print(result)
            continue`

Comment: Did you read my question? In my real case I am using the `DictReader` so I have no control over what the function returns or yields.

Comment: I saw the code that simulates the error ... and didn't think be side it ... sorry

Comment: But sincerly, after exploring the net for a solution to you problem... my thought is renounce this DictReader ,,, and make your custom class... for csv is not a such big performance impact and it will be more "readabble" and you will have more control over errors